# How can I group a sorted DataFrame on a stopping criterion?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the pandas DataFrame below which is already sorted on column `A`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': range(15),
        'B': range(5)*3}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# just in case:
df.sort('A', inplace=True)
```

The resulting dataframe looks something like this:

```
A  | B
-----
0  | 0
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 4
5  | 0
6  | 1
7  | 2
8  | 3
9  | 4
10 | 0
11 | 1
12 | 2
13 | 3
14 | 4
```

I would like to group this into three groups based on the "stopping points" in column `B` where the value of that column goes down from 4 to 0. A naive use of groupby can't accommodate this because there is no key that distinguishes groups.

It would be straightforward to do this by iterating over the individual rows in sorted order, but I was wondering if there was a pandas-native solution.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can create new column `C` for groupby by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['C'] = ((df.B == 0).cumsum())

print (df)
     A  B  C
0    0  0  1
1    1  1  1
2    2  2  1
3    3  3  1
4    4  4  1
5    5  0  2
6    6  1  2
7    7  2  2
8    8  3  2
9    9  4  2
10  10  0  3
11  11  1  3
12  12  2  3
13  13  3  3
14  14  4  3

print (df.groupby('C').sum())
    A   B
C        
1  10  10
2  35  10
3  60  10
```

Or better `groupby` by `Series`:

```
print (df[['A','B']].groupby([((df.B == 0).cumsum())]).sum())
    A   B
B        
1  10  10
2  35  10
3  60  10
```

For storing groups is possible use `dict` comprehension:

```
for i, g in df[['A','B']].groupby([((df.B == 0).cumsum())]):
    print (i)
    print (g)    

1
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
2
   A  B
5  5  0
6  6  1
7  7  2
8  8  3
9  9  4
3
     A  B
10  10  0
11  11  1
12  12  2
13  13  3
14  14  4

dfs = {i-1: g for i,g in df[['A','B']].groupby([((df.B == 0).cumsum())])}
print (dfs[0])
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is exactly what I needed.